# Jetzt vs. eben vs. einfach

Tags: english-to-german, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, grammaticality, standard-german

Is either *einfach*, *gerade*, or *jetzt* the German equivalent to *just* in English? For example,

> He just called me.

Is the German translation

> 1. Er hat mich *eben* angerufen?
> 2. Er hat mich *gerade* angerufen?
> 3. Er hat mich *einfach* angerufen?

Or is *einfach* just used to express imperative phrases? For example,

> Gehst du *einfach* in den Supermarkt!
>   
>   (Meaning just go to the supermarket?)

Thanks guys.:)

Comment: *mich*, anstatt *mir*

Comment: @Björn Friedrich Danke dir

Comment: @c.p. Danke dir

Comment: "Geh einfach in den Supermarkt!"

Answer (score 6):

I'd say it depends on the meaning of "just" in the english sentence: `He just called me`as in `he called just a minute ago` could be

> Er hat mich gerade eben angerufen
>
> Er hat mich gerade angerufen
>
> Er hat mich eben angerufen

but `einfach`  would be wrong in this context.

If you want to express some kind of surprise or indignation, as in `He just called me! Without further consideration!` then it would be

> Er hat mich einfach angerufen
>
> Er hat mich einfach so angerufen

Or another possibility, as in `He didn't even come to my place, he just called me`:

> Er hat mich nur angerufen
>
> Er hat mich einfach nur angerufen

Answer (score 4):

`"Geh (jetzt) einfach in den Supermarkt!"` would indeed be `Just go to the supermarket (already)!`. Nike's slogan `just do it` can be translated as `Mach es einfach`.

On the other hand, "einfach" can also mean `simple` (eine einfache Mathematikaufgabe; opposite of "schwierig") and `once` (not twice): "Eine einfache Wiederholung" could thus mean "a one-time repetition", but also "a simple repetition". "Geh einfach in den Supermarkt" could be interpreted as "please don't go twice", but that's a bit of a stretch, because nobody would say it like this normally, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

All three translations are correct.

*Er hat mich eben angerufen?*
and 
*Er hat mich gerade angerufen?* 
are basically equivalent and express a temporal relation.
In some regions of Germany, people might consider *eben* to be a bit further in the past than *gerade*, but the difference is insignificant.

The third translation re-translated to English might be *He simply called me*.

I can't think of any phrases or sentences, where *einfach* would express an imperative. If you say, for instance, *Mach es einfach!*, the imperative is the verb machen, not the adverb einfach.